# Drop down to display image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am very new to code, but I was wondering what direction I should go with this code. I am going to have a drop down menu where you can pick a color and an image will be displayed in the preview box. I need each of the color1 color2 and color3 images be displayed all at the same time in the preview box. They also need to be able to change when other colors are picked. If anyone could give some sort of direction that would be awesome :) oh I also have my image set up in a sprite

Here is the code that I have so far :

```
<style>
    * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
    #preview {
        display: block;
        width: 270px;
        height: 270px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

</style>
```

```
<div id="preview">
    <img id="image" src="image.png" />
</div>

<form action="" id="opts">
    <label for="color1">Front Color</label>
    <select name="color1" id="color1">
        <option value="white" selected="">white</option>
        <option value="black">black</option>
        <option value="red">red</option>
        <option value="blue">blue</option>
        <option value="gold">gold</option>
        <option value="pink">pink</option>
        <option value="purple">purple</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label for="color2">Middle Color</label>
    <select name="color2" id="color1">
        <option value="white">white</option>
        <option value="black">black</option>
        <option value="red">red</option>
        <option value="blue">blue</option>
        <option value="gold">gold</option>
        <option value="pink">pink</option>
        <option value="purple">purple</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label for="color3">Back Color</label>
    <select name="color3" id="color1">
        <option value="white">white</option>
        <option value="black">black</option>
        <option value="red">red</option>
        <option value="blue">blue</option>
        <option value="gold">gold</option>
        <option value="pink">pink</option>
        <option value="purple">purple</option>
    </select>
</form>

 <script>

        function setcolor1() {
            var img = document.getElementById("image");
            img.src = this.value;
            return false;
        }
        document.getElementById("color1").onchange = setcolor1;
        }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you write JS or jQuery(whichever you prefer) to change background color onhover or onclick, that way your image looks like different color a user clicks on color button. Buttons improve the UX (user-experience) and have feel much better than strolling through option list.

Also

```
#preview {
display: block;
width: 270px;
height: 270px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

is not good for responsive web design/development

instead you should put the following:

```
html
{
width:100%;
}

#preview
{
width:10.5% (this percentage may change depending on how big you want this to cover your page)
max-width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using jquery you can solve this .You have used same id for all select boxes need to change.I suggest to use the code like-

```
**html**

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="preview">
    <img id="image" src="image.png" />
</div>

<form action="" id="opts">
    <label for="color1">Front Color</label>
    <select name="color1" id="color1">
        <option value="white" selected="">white</option>
        <option value="black">black</option>
        <option value="red">red</option>
        <option value="blue">blue</option>
        <option value="gold">gold</option>
        <option value="pink">pink</option>
        <option value="purple">purple</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label for="color3">Back Color</label>
    <select name="color3" id="color3">
        <option value="white">white</option>
        <option value="black">black</option>
        <option value="red">red</option>
        <option value="blue">blue</option>
        <option value="gold">gold</option>
        <option value="pink">pink</option>
        <option value="purple">purple</option>
    </select>
</form>

**css**
    * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
    #preview {
        display: block;
        width: 270px;
        height: 270px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
#image{
    width:100px;
}

**jquery**

        $(function(){
            $('#color1').change(function()
            {
                var e = document.getElementById("color1");
                var col = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
                $('#preview').css('color', col);
               src='a.png';
                $('#preview img').attr("src", src);
        });
            $('#color3').change(function()
            {
                var e = document.getElementById("color3");
                var col = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
                $('#preview').css('background-color', col);
        });

      });
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/56ncdh40/1/)